# When inserting null value in database for date field, it's taking 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to pass an empty value when date input is not provided by user. I'm passing null but when displaying it's showing like this `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM`

`FollowUpDate` field is `datetime` datatype

```
if (txtFollowupDate.Text !="")
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FollowUpDate", FollowUpDate);    
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FollowUpDate", "");
}
```

Comment: add a `DBNull.Value` not an emptry string `""`

Comment: check the default value for this column in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use null value and not an empty string:

```
 if (txtFollowupDate.Text !="")
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FollowUpDate", FollowUpDate);
 }
 else
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FollowUpDate", DBNull.Value);
 }
```

Comment: when im displaying value its giving error- String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Then set NULL as default value for your procedure param and do not add it in csae it is empty (remove else branch)

Comment: Presumably FollowUpDate is incorrectly formatted then

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing null, you're passing empty string, which gets converted to `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM`.

You should use `DBNull.Value` instead.

**edit**

Are you sure you don't mean something like this:

```
if (txtFollowupDate.Text !="")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FollowUpDate", txtFollowupDate.Text);

    }
```

I was just wondering where the `FollowUpDate` variable is coming from.

Comment: while displaying getting error

  DateTime followupdt = Convert.ToDateTime(FollowUpDate);

Answer (score 0):

In the case of interacting with database, you should add DBNull.Value instead of null.

You can use the below extension method to accomplish this.

```
public static void AddValueorDefaultToParams(this SqlCommand cmd, string paramName, string value)
 {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramName))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, value);
            }
            else
            {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, DBNull.Value);
            }
        }

}
```

Usage

```
cmd.AddValueorDefaultToParams("@FollowUpDate", FollowUpDate);
```